# Javascript - regex odd number of quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this javascript regex expression:

```
var reg = new RegExp("(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))");
```

How could I escape the quotes so that the quotes are contained, since right now, they overflow, and quote the lines after it.

Edit:
regex expanded:

```
(?xi)
\b
(                           # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    [a-z][\w-]+:                # URL protocol and colon
    (?:
      /{1,3}                        # 1-3 slashes
      |                             #   or
      [a-z0-9%]                     # Single letter or digit or '%'
                                # (Trying not to match e.g. "URI::Escape")
    )
    |                           #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]               # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                           # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                      # Run of non-space, non-()<>
    |                               #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                           # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                                   #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)
```

Comment: Your problem is too much regex.

Comment: As you would normally escape the quote, with a backslash `\\`

Comment: Also remember is JS regex strings that you should double escape anything that you'd need to escape in the regex itself

Comment: Show actual input and excepted output instead of an unreadable regex. We'll then probably be able to answer your question ;)

Comment: @sp00m the actual input is any string that the user inputs, and the regex is supposed to match uris and make anchor tags out of them. I got the regex from http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: This is about as obtuse and unreadable as one can get.  Remember, the winner isn't the one who figures out how to solve the nastiest problem on one regex.  The winner is the one who writes reliable code that those who come after you can understand and maintain without introducing new bugs.  I don't know what problem you're actually trying to solve with the regex (because it's sooo unreadable), but I'd probably write multiple lines of code to break this problem into smaller pieces.

Comment: @jfriend00 Question was edited with expanded regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use the native declaration form of regex in javascript:

```
var reg = /regex here/;
```

Then, you can freely use quotes in the regex without escaping anything.  You will have to escape any forward slashes in the regex by putting a backslash in front of it.

If you want to stick with the string form, then you can escape a quote with a backslash in front of it to keep it from being a string terminator:

```
var reg = new RegExp('My dog\'s breath');
```